# Is there an iPad app to play movies from an SD card?

Tags: ipad, applications, software-recommendation, movie, sd-card

Is there an iPad application which is capable of playing iPad compatible movie files from an SD card via the Apple Camera Connection Kit?
I prefer App Store apps, no jailbreak apps please.

Comment: Has anything changed about the situation since 2011? Like with Documents and Custom Actions in iOS 8.

Answer (score 5):

The "Camera Connection Kit" is called that for a specific reason. The USB and SD Card readers are meant to either directly connect your camera to it, or just the SD card from it.

This means also that the readers only function with the Photos application, and nothing else. This is also the reason why most external keyboards don't work anymore.

There is no SDK access to the Camera Connection Kit, so third-party apps may not use it.

IIRC, Movies taken by your camera are imported into the Photos app as well. I do not recall whether or not you can view them from within the Photos app.

Comment: Yes you can view them from the Photos app. I was hoping that SDK access to the Kit would be possible and somebody came up with a movie player. That would be a nice open source project, so devs could compile the sources as an adhoc app (no jailbreaking required).

Comment: Well, that being the case, I suppose you can put movies on the SD Card, import them, and play them in Photos.app...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what I was searching for:
[zoomIt](http://www.zoomitonline.com/)

It's a piece of hardware that connects to the iPad. With their application you can then access SD cards. According to their [app description](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zoomit-for-ipad/id380603231) you can:

> - display/view a file with a format supported by SDK3.0 or higher

Unfortunately it costs another 60$ and I already bought the Apple Camera Connection Kit.
If anybody tested watching movies with this thing a little comment is very welcome.